The persistent store "act.JMSJDBCStore" does not exist
iam try to starting the manager sever getting  this error
in data sources ip configuration all are correct
JMSServer.act.JMSServer      Failed Symtom{JMS_ERROR,HIGH,act.JMSServer,weblogic.management.DeploymentException:
Internal error activating the JMS Server act.JMSServer: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: The persistent store
"act.JMSJDBCStore" does not exist}
any one knows this one,please update it's helpfull for me
persistent store
"act.JMSJDBCStore" does not exist
JMSJDBCStore configuration level  or any libires are misssing?
